# is it possible to change a entity property doctrine type dynamically?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity property which is mapped to doctrine type text, its underling database column type is  longtext in which  different data will be saved into, such as int, text, custom doctrine type, I want to change its doctrine type dynamically , so that doctrine can handle data type automatically. for example,

`<field name="value" column="value" type="text" />`

this field will be feeding data form the text form field type, also a custom form type MoneyType,  this form type will construct currency,amount into a Money object, I also customize a doctrine type called money , this will convert money to string vise versa, so I need to change this value field doctrine type depending on the data that is  coming.  is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to be certain there is no misconfusion : to answer the question in your title, no you can not (to my knowledge) change dynamically a Doctrine entity type.

However, for your example, the solution may be to use [data transformers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html). It will enable to change the data once it has been input by the user, and do whatever you want with it. In the absence of code, I can only encourage you to read this.

Hope this helps.